# How to log these 5 minutes with awk and then convert the output to another file

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos

I have a log file whose name is listlog, the content is:

```
2021-08-12 16:09:17 textsp sdgg
reponse:success
prams:invalid
line 3
2021-08-12 16:10:17 textdfdfdlfs sfdfs
reponse: failed
prams:valid
line 3
```

I want to filter the logs recorded between t1 and t2 and print the log line with 2 consecutive lines. I wrote using awk with if condition and grep. But I got the error:

This is the content I want to filter and write to a new file assuming t1 < (16:09:17, 16:19:17) < t2 :

```
2021-08-12 16:09:17 textsp sdgg
reponse:success
prams:invalid
2021-08-12 16:10:17 textdfdfdlfs sfdfs
reponse: failed
prams:valid
```

here is the awk script i wrote:

```
t1=$(date -d "$min_change minutes ago" +"%F %T")
t2=$(date +"%F %T")
cat $listlog | awk -v t1="$t1" -v t2="$t2" -v listlog="$listlog" '{
        if (match($0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}))
        {
                if ( $0 > t1 && $0 < t2 | $0 ~ t2 )
                {
                        grep -A 2 $0 $listlog >> /tmp/temp.txt
                }
        }
        }'
```

This is the error I get:

```
awk: cmd. line:2:       if (match($0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}))
awk: cmd. line:2:                       ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:3:       if (match($0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}))
awk: cmd. line:3:                                                ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:4:               if ( $0 > t1 && $0 < t2 | $0 ~ t2 )
awk: cmd. line:4:                                         ^ syntax error.
awk: cmd. line:5:               if ( $0 > t1 && $0 < t2 | $0 ~ t2 ) 
awk: cmd. line:5:                                                   ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:6:                       grep -A 2 $0 $listlog >> /temp/temp.txt
awk: cmd. line:6:                                             ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:7:                       grep -A 2 $0 $listlog >> /temp/temp.txt.
awk: cmd. line:7:                                                                ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: For the record, this appears to be a follow-up on [how to get log lines written to a file within the last 5 minutes?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/664366)

Comment: I did give an approach at getting logs between two dates there. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to even begin describing what's wrong with your script, but here's a summary of the most important points:

1. What you've written isn't an `awk` script.  it's not even an `awk` script embedded within a shell script (which would normally be perfectly OK).  It's
   a weird mixture of some shell code, with an attempt at an `awk` script that includes shell code within it (`awk` doesn't interpret or run shell commands).

   You can't run `grep` like that inside `awk`, not without forking it as an external process, anyway.  And there's no need to do that because `awk` can do regex pattern matching.
2. You have no indentation in any of your code, making it extremely difficult to read.

   UPDATE: I just edited your question to re-format it, and it turns out you did have some indentation in your code.  But you'd formatted it with HTML `<br/>` tags instead of using the markdown editor's built-in text formatting abilities.
3. Points 1 and 2, are probably why you've had no answers or even comments in the 7 hours since you posted your question.  The initial reaction of any reader (mine, at least) would be "WTF? That makes no sense. I don't even know where to begin...pass".
4. You can't do date comparisons in shell or `awk` the way you're attempting to do them.  To do numeric comparisons like greater-than or less-than, you need to convert the dates to numbers (i.e. unix `time_t` format, seconds since the "epoch", which is Midnight on Jan 1 1970, UTC).
5. It is possible to do what you want in `awk`, but it'll be harder than necessary because `awk` doesn't have any built-in date conversion functions.  It would be significantly easier in `perl`, which does have good date & time library functions.  Which is a good thing for you, because your script as written is much closer to `perl` code in style than `awk` code.

---

Here's a fairly simple, straight-forward way of doing what you want in perl.  It takes command line arguments (using perl's [Getopt::Std](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Std) library module).    `Getopt::Std` is a core perl library module and is included with perl.

The arguments can be provided in any order.  None of the option arguments (`-m`, `-n`, and `-s`) are mandatory, they all have default values if not provided on the command line.  Any args which aren't handled by `Getopt::Std` are treated as input filenames.  The script can process stdin as well as any input filenames, so you can pipe your log file into it.

The script also uses the [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse) module from the perl [Time::Date](https://metacpan.org/release/TimeDate) collection to convert date strings to seconds since the epoch.

`Date::Parse` is not included with perl, it needs to be installed.  If you're using Debian (or Ubuntu or Mint or other Debian-related distros) you run install it with `sudo apt-get install libtimedate-perl`.  Most other distros will have it packaged too.   The Centos package is [perl-TimeDate-2.30-2](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/perl-TimeDate-2.30-2.el7.noarch.rpm.html) for Centos 7, or [perl-TimeDate-2.30-15](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-appstream-aarch64/perl-TimeDate-2.30-15.module_el8.3.0+416+9a1a0b3f.noarch.rpm.html) for Centos 8.
Otherwise, you can install it with `cpan`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use Date::Parse;

my %opts;
getopt('m:s:n:', \%opts); # -m minutes, -s start time, -n number of lines

my $st  = $opts{s} || -1; # start time, default now.
my $min = $opts{m} ||  5; # number of minutes after $st to match, default 5.
my $nl  = $opts{n} ||  2; # No. of extra lines to print after match, default 2.

if ($st == -1) {
  $st = time();           # now
} else {
  $st = str2time($st);    # convert time string to seconds since epoch
};
my $et = $st + $min * 60; # calculate ending time

my $p = -1; # input lines are printed only when $p > -1

# main loop, read and process all input file(s).
while (<>) {
  if (m/^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/) {
    my $t = str2time($1);
    $p = $nl if ($t >= $st && $t <= $et);
  };

  if ($p > -1) { print; $p-- };
};
```

Save it as, e.g. `extract.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x extract.pl` and run it like this:

```
$ ./extract.pl -s "2021-08-12 16:09:00" -n 2 -m 5 listlog 
2021-08-12 16:09:17 textsp sdgg
reponse:success
prams:invalid
2021-08-12 16:10:17 textdfdfdlfs sfdfs
reponse: failed
prams:valid
```

You can redirect the output if required, e.g. by appending `>>/tmp/temp.txt` to the end of the command line.